# JQuery Mobile / Phonegap Panels nested swiping

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile as the backdrop for an Html5 IOS app I'm building.

The app brief requires sliding panels to display Notifications (left swipe) and Contact info (right swipe).  This works fine with the below code, but I also need to add in a nested swipe for a banner slider that requires left and right triggers also - so I need to react differently when swiping over the 'bannerArea'div rather than the rest of the page.

js -

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#demo-page", function() {
  $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function( e ) {
    if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
        if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
            $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
        } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
            $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
        }
    }
   });
 });
```

html -

```
<div data-role="page" id="demo-page"  data-url="demo-page">
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" class="main_nav" data-display="push"  data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a">
    <div class="nav_profile">
        <div class="nav_name">
            <h3>Notifications</h3>
            <p>Blah</p>
            <p>Blah</p>
        </div><!--/nav_name-->
    </div><!--/nav_profile-->
</div>
<div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-position="right" class="main_nav" data-display="push"  data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a">
    <div class="nav_profile">
        <div class="nav_name">
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <p>Blah</p>
            <p>Blah</p>
        </div><!--/nav_name-->
    </div><!--/nav_profile-->
</div>
<!-- /panel -->
<div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" role="banner" >
    <h3 class="hp">Zoe<span>Personal Trainer</span></h3>
    <a href="#left-panel" data-rel="panel" data-role="button" class="menu_icon left notifPanelLink" ></a>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="background">
    <div class=" notificationArea">
    NotifBlock
    </div>
    <div class="bannerArea">

    </div>



</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone recommend the best solution for this - I am thinking of adding a if not '.bannerArea' statement within the swipe script but wonder whether there's a better solution?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would implement your if not '.bannerArea' solution.

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#demo-page", function() {
   $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function( e ) {
   if($(e.target).closest('div.bannerArea').length==0)
   {
    if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
        if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
            $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
        } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
            $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
    }
   }
   else {
   /** HANDLE THE BANNER SWIPE HERE**/
   }

  }
 });
});
```